# "whl" or "wheel" tag for Python package format?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

There seems to be two separate tags, [whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whl) and [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel).

Which is preferred?

One of my Q's just got an edit where the only change was one tag swapped for the other, should I roll that back?

Comment: *wheel* seems better to me.

Comment: Quite valid, Martijn, though IUAM `wheel,python` or `whl,python` are enough? OT: Your omnipresence is getting scary ;-)

Comment: If that was a *suggested edit*, I would personally roll it back and then comment on the question asking users not to submit suggested edits like that.

Comment: I've made the changes now.

Comment: `wheel` used to have a few hundred questions but most of them weren't about .whl files, it was a hodge-podge of stuff about colour wheels,  mouse wheels, whatever other random stuff.  a while ago I moved the python questions over to `whl` to at least group them in a sensible way.  Martijn's `python-wheel` is a better name and would have been a better choice in hindsight

Answer (score 13):

Neither should be. [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) is ambiguous and likely to clash with other projects, [whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whl) is not very helpful or discoverable. No-one will subscribe to [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel), for example, when there are also dozens of questions about mouse wheels and rotating galleries and physical Android device wheels being asked.

We really need a [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel) here; it covers the load better and cannot possibly be confused for any other project with similar names, now or in the future.

Whatever way this goes, the tags we don't pick should be made synonyms or should be manually retagged.

---

**Update**: I've implemented this now; I've retagged all *Python* `whl` and `wheel` questions to use [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel), and altered the tag wiki on [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) to make it more generic.

Comment: Why not create the [tag:python-wheel]?

Comment: @cybermonkey: I thought we'd discuss it first before diving in.

Comment: talk about reinventing the wheel!  you missed one python whl question though

Comment: @wim: done that one now.