# Do we really need to reinvent the [wheel]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

At time of writing this post originally, the [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) tag has 4 followers and 201 questions tagged.

The tag wiki info says:

> Wheels are round things, that rotate. Many mice have wheels, as do many compact devices where a wheel can be a helpful input device.
>
> Consider using more descriptive tags instead however to tag your questions with.
>
> For the Python packaging format, see [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel).

I can't really see how this tag helps to categorize programming related questions (beyond the python packaging format<sup>1</sup>).

*"Wheels are round things, that rotate. Many mice have wheels ..."*
***Seriously??***<sup>2</sup>

*"Consider using more descriptive tags instead however to tag your questions with."*
Looks like the tag invalidates its usage itself.

---

#### Update

As requested in the [burnination process requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) I'm going to get in more detail as [required criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/8242698):

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Most of the times not, and the tag info wiki is let's say *"naive"*.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

*Wheels* aren't primarily related to programming. There are programming related concepts though (see **Other considerations**)

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Obviously not. Almost every modern homo sapiens will discover the principle of a *wheel* playing around with their toys at the age of 2 or 3 or so.
Physical details like minimization of friction or such are mostly covered by basic school knowledge.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Obviously not. See the list of examples below.

Here are some examples how the tag fails to improve related questions (just the current top ten):

- **[Win Wheel not working on mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449765/win-wheel-not-working-on-mobile-browser)**
  It's completely unclear what that *wheel* input should be. The question just provides some 3rd party links.
- **[How to find initial velocity and distance traveled on each loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775351/how-to-find-initial-velocity-and-distance-traveled-on-each-loop-iteration)**
  Not programming related. [trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) probably fits better than [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel)
- **[Rotate number wheel and get the random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427321/rotate-number-wheel-and-get-the-random-number)**
  Unclear, too broad. What's *number wheel*?
- **[holonomic robot with three wheel drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196895/holonomic-robot-with-three-wheel-drive)**
  Unclear. Hardware related not programming?
- **[How can I create a rotating group of triangles that I can click on to have an effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877290/how-can-i-create-a-rotating-group-of-triangles-that-i-can-click-on-to-have-an-ef)**
  Unclear, too broad.
- **[Wheel view selected item with color change and having box shape border in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650486/wheel-view-selected-item-with-color-change-and-having-box-shape-border-in-androi)**  Unclear, no example. *wheel-view* seems to be something android specific.
- **[Android custom “Wheel” control like Google Photo app rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739662/android-custom-wheel-control-like-google-photo-app-rotation)**
  Asks for 3rd party ressource.
- **[Rotation of wheels of a car in unity 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286117/rotation-of-wheels-of-a-car-in-unity-5)**
  OK, this really refers to *wheels*. Uhhm, but wait ... where do the *mice* come in play here?
- **[Rotary wheel does not show the effect of ease In and ease Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952630/rotary-wheel-does-not-show-the-effect-of-ease-in-and-ease-out)**
  Again: What have the *mice* to do with it?
- **[R circlular wheel chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798359/r-circlular-wheel-chart)**
  Should rather refer to [wheel-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel-chart), whatever this is.

---

#### Other considerations

A renaming option for that tag seems to be [wheel-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel-device) so the relation to the hardware is made clear (tag info proposal):

> > #### [wheel-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel-device)
> >
> > - A mechanical hardware input component that enables to translate angular transitions to discrete positive or negative integer step
> >       values depending on the clock- or counter clock-wise direction of the
> >       input event.
> >
> >   A [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) combined with an [A/D
> >       Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter)
> >       is a feasible implementation.
> >
> >   An alternative implementation example is a capacitive input component, like Apple realized with the famous [iPod UI
> >       design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod#Interface).
> > - There are also touch screen/pad UI simulations of such hardware input devices, which need to be distinguished further regarding the UI
> >       framework. The principle still is the same, translate a clock- or
> >       counter-clock- wise circular gesture to a positive or negative step
> >       value.
> >
> > **Note:** General reference to *wheels* as physical or metaphysical devices (as for e.g. these [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel)) isn't programming related, and you should elaborate your specific relation in your question instead.
> >
> > **Tag Synonyms:** [wheel-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel-input)[wheel-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel-control)

---

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>At least we should consider to create a tag synonym for [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) and [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel).</sub>

<sup>2)</sup> [The intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBkT19uH2RQ)

> *Brain*: 
>   Run this wheel now, we're going to rule the world!
>   *Pinky*: Mice on wheels was your best idea ever master!

Comment: Who the hell thought this was an acceptable tag?

Comment: I'm strictly against making that a synonym. I say burn the [tag:wheel].

Comment: I started reviewing the questions with this tag and all I saw could either be changed to [tag:python-wheel] or [tag:wheel] could be removed without loosing relevant context. A lot of the non-Python questions are bad, too, I started CV-ing them (and requested CV on some of them).

Comment: Renaming does not make sense either. There are only few questions about hardware-wheels and those which are have better tags instead (e.g. encoder). Tags are not keywords and we should not have more useless tags. (I just found [tag:radial], which also seems to be pointless; it has not even a wiki text)

Comment: @Olaf I extended my question with an alternative proposal. Didn't look into the questions and how these are affected so much so far.

Comment: @user0042: I noticed the edit and already commented about it. Briefly: I'm against it. Just remove/retag as [tag:python-wheel] and get the torches. The other questions don't really need another tag. About the hardware-wheel: this is a programming site and the problems should be abstract enough not to requre such a tag.

Comment: @Olaf _"Just remove/retag as python-wheel and get the torches."_ I'd be fine with that, just as my original intend.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/whl-or-wheel-tag-for-python-package-format

Comment: At the beginning, I really think the _Many mice have wheels_ is a joke.  But after I put that in google, I found that is may refer to the [scroll wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel) on the computer mouse.

Comment: A quick look at the questions suggests the majority are Python Wheel files, and most of the rest seem to be related to the already existing [tag:mousewheel]. There is also [tag:color-wheel] but no [tag:wheel-control] for the UI element on Android. [tag:wheel-device] is unnecessary IMO. Oh, and as @Prisoner mentions, there's also [tag:scrollwheel], which should be a synonym of [tag:mousewheel].

Comment: "`[wheel]` be better off without it", if we need a fresh pun, and more suits my recommendation of a straight burninating rather than salvaging.

Comment: I retagged all the Python questions, since those had been cleaned up previously [per another Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/whl-or-wheel-tag-for-python-package-format). Still leaves 149 questions

Comment: Mouse wheel events might account for some usages of this tag. But that's why we have a `[mousewheel]` tag....

Comment: There's also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(Unix_term)

Comment: "Many mice have wheels" They're probably more common with hamsters than with mice, though.

Comment: Rotation and circularity are independent features :-)

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring, Q +94/2, Answer telling yes +45/-3, Answer telling no +4/-17

Comment: @shadow, ouh, please look at the comment inside the post before editing a title: now your change is cached and visible by many...

Comment: @Cœur What comment are you referring to precisely? And I fail to see how that's an issue, given the puntastic tradition of burnination requests...

Comment: @Shadow first two lines of the post when you start edition: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/82068694-3f1b-440f-b253-6915d0659493/view-source

Comment: @Cœur I legitimately missed that. Still not sure why puns on the featured page is a bad thing, but I apologise for missing the note.

Comment: I say we reinvent it

Comment: @Amicable What do you think was the original title of this post?

Comment: I say we [wheel] this tag out of here.

Comment: [whe'll] be able to burninate it.

Comment: Big [wheel] keep on turning, Proud Mary keep on burnin'ating

Comment: And it burns, burns, burns... the [wheel] of fire... the [wheel] of fire...

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: +149/-2, Answer saying yes +101/-3, Answer saying no +6/-34. The consensus is to burninate.

Comment: Is there a tag for the Unix `wheel` group? :-)

Answer (score 105):

> Do we really need to reinvent the [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel)?

No, we need to burninate it!

Answer (score 29):

[wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel) should be used whenever the post is related to the [Python package format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/whl-or-wheel-tag-for-python-package-format)
- [mousewheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mousewheel) must be used wherever the post is related to the [mouse scroll wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel)
- [scrollwheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollwheel) must be synonymized with [mousewheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mousewheel)
- [color-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-wheel) must be used whenever referring to the [colour/color wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel) as a UI element.
- <s>Probably a new tag should be created for [Unix Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(Unix_term)).</s> (Questions related to Unix Wheel might be off topic for the site)
- [android-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wheel) This is a separate open source widget wheel selector

## Progress:

The [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=wheel),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwheel%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwheel%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwheel%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwheel%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wheel) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I have added this answer after collecting information from all the comments, do edit it in and add more details. Note that this answer would be later on edited to the [burnination progress answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), if we decide to continue with the burnination.

Comment: `unix-wheel` should be off topic as simply a popular naming convention for system administration, not anything to do with programming.

Comment: @BhargavRao What's the reason for keeping [tag:mousewheel] and synonymizing [tag:scrollwheel] instead of the other way around?

Comment: @jpmc26 [mousewheel] has way more questions than [scrollwheel], so it won't let me suggest a synonym in the other way. (After it is synonymized, I can reverse it.) As for this answer, I took it from the comments where Ken mentions that order. I do feel that this way would be better because, more users are familiar with the term mouse wheel, rather than the scroll wheel. Also, mousewheel has a tag wiki, whereas the other doesn't.

Comment: Dunno if it gets any current use, but also consider the [timer wheel](https://blog.acolyer.org/2015/11/23/hashed-and-hierarchical-timing-wheels/)

Comment: I suggest making `unix-wheel` a synonym for `root` or `superuser`, if there are any questions tagged `wheel` in that sense. I don't hear "wheel" much these days, but "root", "superuser", and "admin" all seem current to me. (of course, it's probably a more useful tag over on superuser than stackoverflow).

Comment: Tbh, I don't think we'll get a chance to create the [unix-wheel] tag, let's wait and see when the actual burnination begins.

Comment: Do any tagged questions relate to [wheel factorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) or wheel sieves?

Comment: I created the [android-wheel] tag, since there's an [actual project](https://github.com/maarek/android-wheel) with code

Comment: @BhargavRao There are no open questions remaining in the tag

Answer (score 0):

I thought the Unity question on wheel rotation in 3D graphics was the most interesting case in which I can't think of a better, more specific tag that isn't confusing. I don't know that questions about wheels in various 3D graphics, games, or modeling packages are common enough that having a tag for them is useful though.

Maybe `wheel-animation`, or `animatedwheel`?

Comment: mice on wheels, mice on wheels, ... (***crescendo***)

Comment: @user0042 - But, are they animated wheels? And are these mice all named Ralph?

Answer (score -32):

My guess is that the tag was defined in that way to discourage its use in favor of more specific ones, such as [python-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wheel).

Personally, if that was the original intention I agree. Some new fancy language or library in the future might have an important component named wheel, so it *is* better to be specific.

If there are so few questions with that tag it seems to be working. Let's not fix what is working. Keep it, I say.

Comment: _My guess is that the tag was defined in that way to discourage its use in favor of more specific ones_ no that would just lead to more mistagging...

Comment: I have the impression that you are making the assumption that python-wheel is the only relevant interpretation that there is and that there always will be. It's a big assumption to make.

Comment: A tag needs to be unambiguous...check the first point in [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/347191).

Comment: That is exactly my point!

Comment: Well.. I dont see why you would want to keep [tag:wheel] then

Comment: By "using up" wheel, you encourage people to use more specific tags. I interpret the low usage as a sign that this is happening in practice.

Comment: As a German, I know why @Rad80 wants to keep the wheel...

Comment: "My guess is that the tag was defined in that way to discourage its use in favor of more specific ones". This seems to indeed be the case. In fact the text was added by one of our esteemed diamond mods. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24347477/revisions. I would assume that they didn't have the energy to start yet another boring tag burnination process and therefore made the edit as a "quick & dirty" fix.

Comment: @JFMeier As a german I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: I'll clarify: the tag should be blacklisted. I believe that removing it without blacklisting will result in a new, inappropriate, wheel tag. To prevent that, the current definition was created and should stay.

Comment: @Rad80 Then we deal with the new, inappropriate tags when they arise. That's how this works. We shouldn't keep Bad Tag X just because people might make Bad Tag Y